# NameError: function name is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

I am programming a small Python module with Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) and I am using IPython 1.2.1 for running my program.

This module will contain several mathematical function evaluations with power series. I am separating python function definitions from python function tests.

Here is my **code for PowerSeries.py** :

```
### Computations of some functions by power series ###

def exp(x):
    """Exponential function"""
    exp=1.0
    term=1.0
    iteration=1
    factorial=1
    while(abs(term/factorial)>1e-10):
        factorial*=iteration
        term*=x
        exp+=term/factorial
        iteration+=1
    return exp

def hyperbolicCosine(x):
    """Hyperbolic cosine function"""
    cosh=1.0
    term=1.0
    iteration=1
    factorial=1
    while(abs(term/factorial)>1e-10):
        factorial*=iteration
        term*=x
        if iteration%2==0:
            cosh+=term/factorial
        iteration+=1
   return cosh

def sine(x):
    """Sine function"""
    sine=0.0
    term=1.0
    iteration=1
    factorial=1
    while(abs(term/factorial)>1e-10):
        factorial*=iteration
        term*=x
        if iteration%2==1:
            sine+=term/factorial                
            term=-term
        iteration+=1
    return sine

def cosine(x):
    """Cosine function"""
    cosine=1.0
    term=1.0
    iteration=1
    factorial=1
    while(abs(term/factorial)>1e-10):
        factorial*=iteration
        term*=x
        if (iteration)%2==0:
            term=-term
            cosine+=term/factorial              
        iteration+=1
    return cosine
```

Here is my **code for tests.py** :

```
### Tests for PowerSeries Module ###
from math import pi
from PowerSeries import *

# Tests of exponential
print "### Tests of exponential ###"
x=-2
print("x=%f exp(x)=%.10f" % (x,exp(x)))
x=-1
print("x=%f exp(x)=%.10f" % (x,exp(x)))
x=0
print("x=%f exp(x)=%.10f" % (x,exp(x)))
x=1
print("x=%f exp(x)=%.10f" % (x,exp(x)))
x=2
print("x=%f exp(x)=%.10f" % (x,exp(x)))

# Tests of hyperbolic cosine
print "### Tests of hyperbolic cosine ###"
x=-2
print("x=%f cosh(x)=%.10f" % (x,hyperbolicCosine(x)))
x=-1
print("x=%f cosh(x)=%.10f" % (x,hyperbolicCosine(x)))
x=0
print("x=%f cosh(x)=%.10f" % (x,hyperbolicCosine(x)))
x=1
print("x=%f cosh(x)=%.10f" % (x,hyperbolicCosine(x)))
x=2
print("x=%f cosh(x)=%.10f" % (x,hyperbolicCosine(x)))


# Tests of sine
print "### Tests of sine ###"
x=0
print("x=%f sin(x)=%.10f" % (x,sine(x)))
x=pi/6
print("x=%f sin(x)=%.10f" % (x,sine(x)))
x=pi/4
print("x=%f sin(x)=%.10f" % (x,sine(x)))
x=pi/3
print("x=%f sin(x)=%.10f" % (x,sine(x)))
x=pi/2
print("x=%f sin(x)=%.10f" % (x,sine(x)))

# Tests of cosine
print "### Tests of cosine ###"
x=0
print("x=%f cos(x)=%.10f" % (x,cosine(x)))
x=pi/6
print("x=%f cos(x)=%.10f" % (x,cosine(x)))
x=pi/4
print("x=%f cos(x)=%.10f" % (x,cosine(x)))
x=pi/3
print("x=%f cos(x)=%.10f" % (x,cosine(x)))
x=pi/2
print("x=%f cos(x)=%.10f" % (x,cosine(x)))
```

Everything works fine until I add the hyperbolicCosine definition.
Executing the tests.py file gives a NameError that I can't solve :

```
     19 print "### Tests of hyperbolic cosine ###"
     20 x=-2
---> 21 print("x=%f cosh(x)=%.10f" % (x,hyperbolicCosine(x)))
     22 x=-1
     23 print("x=%f cosh(x)=%.10f" % (x,hyperbolicCosine(x)))

NameError: name 'hyperbolicCosine' is not defined
```

Help is welcome.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't somehow have an old .pyc file that has a later date than your .py file, or a .py file in a different different directory than the one you think you are using?  Rename PowerSeries.py temporarily and import it under a different name.

Comment: How are you running the `tests.py` code , can you show the exact commad? Is it from within the ipython interpreter?

Comment: Well, I run the tests.py code from within the ipython interpreter with the command **run tests.py**. But according to Patrick Maupin, I actually solved the error by deleting an old **PowerSeries.pyc** file. So, it works now and I will add more function definitions with that problem occurence in mind. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment because I am too new, but it's always is a better idea to explicitly import what you need from a particular module. If you always do that, it could help narrow down the problem in the future (i.e. you will get an ImportError instead of a NameError.)

Moreover, .pyc files are regenerated based on timestamp. It seems like this problem is more likely due to iPython having the old module in memory.

Comment: Yes you're right veggie1. I was too lazy to type in the function names. But I've corrected that yet. Moreover,I am a new ipython user. I don't know well how it works yet. I think I have to dig into a tutorial explaining the mechanism for importing modules and associated commands. Thank you for your advice.